# Query to compare two databases and find only those paid after retire date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help figuring out how to write a query against the employee database's employees table that will generate a list of all employees (EMPY_ID) and their retirement dates (RETIRE_DT) then take those results and run a second query against the payroll database's paychecks table looking for all payments (PAY_DT) made to the employee (EMPY_ID) after they retire (RETIRE_DT). I have this so far but I think I am heading down the wrong path. Still learning. Any help is appreciated.

```sql
WITH R as (select p.* from [paydatabase].[dbo].[PAY_DT] p 
inner join [employeedb].[dbo].[employees] e on p.EMPY_ID = e.EMPY_ID where e.RETIRE_DT <= '2020-01-01')
SELECT * FROM R WHERE PAY_DT >= '2020-01-01'
```

Comment: Do you not want to compare `e.RETIRE_DT` with `p.PAY_DT`? Also why are you using a CTE, doesn't seem necessary here?

Comment: I am still learning and that was what I came up with. Yes the goal is to compare the RETIRE_DT to the PAY_DT and pull out all the paychecks paid to the person after they retired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea is:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM [employeedb].[dbo].[employees] e JOIN
     [paydatabase].[dbo].[PAY_DT] p
     ON p.EMPY_ID = e.EMPY_ID AND
        p.PAY_DT >= e.RETIRE_DT;
```

That is, you want to compare the pay date to the retirements date, not to a constant.

Comment: I don't want to specify the retire date. I want the query to find the RETIRE_DT in the table for the EMLY_ID and use it to compare against the PAY_DT associated with the same EMPY_ID in the pay database. Then list all payments made to that employee after they retired

Comment: @Joe820 . . . I included that date because your query seems fixated on that date.  I removed it from the answer.